# Approximate an expression with condition

Tags: approximation

I do the following computation:

```
CollectPattern[expr_, patt_, args___] := 
 Collect[expr, DeleteDuplicates[Cases[expr, patt, -1]], args];

V[ϕ_] = 3 H0^2 Mpl^2 + gϵ^2 f^4 ω[ϕ];
H[ϕ_] = Sqrt[V[ϕ]/(3 Mpl^2)];
FPV = D[ℏ/(8 Pi^2) D[H[ϕ]^3 P[ϕ, t], ϕ] + (
    V'[ϕ] P[ϕ, t])/(3 H[ϕ]), ϕ] + 3 H[ϕ] P[ϕ, t] - D[P[ϕ, t], t];

Series[FPV, {gϵ, 0, 2}]*(3 H0)/(gϵ^2 f^2) // 
 CollectPattern[#, 
   Derivative[_, 0][P][ϕ, t] | Derivative[0, _][P][ϕ, t] | 
    P[ϕ, t], FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {H0 > 0}] &] &
```

where I expand the FPV equation at leading order in $g_{\epsilon}$. And I get

> $P[\phi, t]\left(\frac{9 H_0^{2}}{f^{2} g \epsilon^{2}}+\frac{3 f^{2} \omega[\phi]}{2 M_{Pl}^{2}}+f^{2}\left(1+\frac{3 H_0^{2} \hbar}{16 M_{Pl}^{2} \pi^{2}}\right) \omega^{\prime \prime}[\phi]\right)-\frac{3 H_0 }{f^{2} g \epsilon^{2}} P^{(0, 1)}[\phi, t]+\frac{1}{8} f^{2}\left(8+\frac{3 H_0^{2} \hbar}{M_{Pl}^{2} \pi^{2}}\right) \omega^{\prime}[\phi] P^{(1, 0)}[\phi, t]+\frac{3 H_0^{2} \hbar\left(\frac{2 H_0^{2}}{g \epsilon^{2}}+\frac{f^{4} \omega[\phi]}{M p l^{2}}\right) }{16 f^{2} \pi^{2}} P^{(2, 0)}[\phi, t]$

I want to ask Mathematica to use the condition $3H_0^2M_P^2 \gg g_{\epsilon}^2f^4$ to approximate the expression, make it to be

$$P[\phi, t]\left(\frac{9 H_0^{2}}{f^{2} g \epsilon^{2}}+f^{2}\left(1+\frac{3 H_0^{2} \hbar}{16 M_{Pl}^{2} \pi^{2}}\right) \omega^{\prime \prime}[\phi]\right)-\frac{3 H_0 }{f^{2} g \epsilon^{2}} P^{(0, 1)}[\phi, t]+\frac{1}{8} f^{2}\left(8+\frac{3 H_0^{2} \hbar}{M_{Pl}^{2} \pi^{2}}\right) \omega^{\prime}[\phi] P^{(1, 0)}[\phi, t]+\frac{3 H_0^{2} \hbar\left(\frac{2 H_0^{2}}{g \epsilon^{2}}\right) }{16 f^{2} \pi^{2}} P^{(2, 0)}[\phi, t]$$

Can Mathematica do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Let expr1 be the result of your code:

```
expr1=P[\[Phi], 
   t] ((9 H0^2)/(f^2 g\[Epsilon]^2) + (3 f^2 \[Omega][\[Phi]])/(
    2 Mpl^2) + 
    f^2 (1 + (3 H0^2 \[HBar])/(
       16 Mpl^2 \[Pi]^2)) (\[Omega]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Phi]]) - (3 H0 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Phi], t])/(f^2 g\[Epsilon]^2) + 
 1/8 f^2 (8 + (3 H0^2 \[HBar])/(Mpl^2 \[Pi]^2)) Derivative[
   1][\[Omega]][\[Phi]] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Phi], t] + (
 3 H0^2 \[HBar] ((2 H0^2)/g\[Epsilon]^2 + (f^4 \[Omega][\[Phi]])/
    Mpl^2) 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Phi], t])/(16 f^2 \[Pi]^2);
```

Let us make the following suvstitution:

```
expr2 = expr1 /. H0 -> (f^2 g\[Epsilon] Sqrt[x])/(Sqrt[3] Mp) // 
  Simplify
```

and expand the result in series around `x=Infinity`:

```
expr3=Series[expr2, {x, \[Infinity], 1}]//Normal
```

Its third term is the main one:

```
expr3[[3]] /. x -> (3 H0^2 Mp^2)/(f^4 g\[Epsilon]^2)

(* (3 H0^4 \[HBar] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Phi], t])/(8 f^2 g\[Epsilon]^2 \[Pi]^2) *)
```

to see it better:

[image]

that's what you are looking for. Have fun!

Comment: Hello, could you please show me explicitly how to get the expression I want in the question? I try to run `expr3 /. x -> (3 H0^2 Mp^2)/(f^4 g\[Epsilon]^2)` but it goes to the original one.

Comment: It is because you take `expr3`, while you need to take `expr3[[3]]`.

Comment: Yes, take `expr3[[3]]` have the same result with your answer. But it only contains $P^{(2,0)}[\phi,t]$ term, I want to know how to get the expression I want in the question, which will contain $P[\phi,t]$, $P^{(1,0)}[\phi,t]$, $P^{(2,0)}[\phi,t]$, $P^{(0,1)}[\phi,t]$ these terms.